# VMPlayer created many vmem files

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-player

I used a 60 gb SSD to host a 50gb Ubuntu install. Now Windows reports that my disk is full

I have a few *.vmem files which accumulated over time for some reason. I'd like to know if it is safe to delete them. They are of the exact same size (3.1gb)

Here are the file names

```
564d8828-32e3-34e4-ecdb-abec5c53bbf4.vmem 
renraku.vmem
renraku-79eb4c7c.vmem
```

I am pretty sure I don't need 3 of those. I also have a bunch of lck directories which might be useless as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after looking briefly on the web, I found your answer, the VMEM file, are file created when your VM is running, or if it crashed. Some turn off the VMEM using auto-scripting (type .vmem on google, it's on the top). If you shuted down your VM then normally, those file should have disappeared, if not, your vm crashed, and that's why they're still there.

Try backing up your vm and delete those file, then run you vm. But normally, you can delete those file (that's what I do on my R&D VM farm).

Hope that's help.

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I realised those files haven't been accessed in a very long time. Thank you

Comment: no problem, glad that you resolved your problem ;)